# How to tell which processes are uploading and downloading data (and how much)?

Tags: command-line, networking, gnome, software-recommendation, monitoring

I can see in my System Monitor that data is being uploaded and downloaded, I can see in Etherape which sites it's connecting to and which protocol is being used. However without looking at the actual packets in WireShark and then finding the port and which process is listening on that port I am unable to tell which processes are uploading and downloading data. So I was wondering if there is an easier way that using WireShark (or some other tool) to find the port manually and then see which process is listening on that port? This application would ideally:

- Give me a list of processes
- Show me (in KiB/s) the amount of data being uploaded and downloaded (in different columns)
- Show me the PIDs of the processes
- Show me the ports which the processes are listening on
- Show me all this information in a table
- Be a CLI program (ideally, but it doesn't have to be in the CLI)
- Have the ability to change the update interval of the data

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18, is there such a software that would meet my needs?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Not me, but honestly these are quite a bit of requirements.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda My bad. I meant to suggest `iftop` not `iotop`.

Comment: @kasperd: Does it match all of my requirements? Because from its description it does not appear to say that it will show processes...

Comment: @ParanoidPanda Looks like it can only display port numbers. I don't think there exist any reliable method to decide which process produced the traffic. There are *heuristics* to figure out which process is using which port, but they won't always produce correct results, and it doesn't look like `iftop` has implemented any such heuristics.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I think the program Nethogs perfectly suits your requirements. From the description:

> NetHogs is a small 'net top' tool. Instead of breaking the traffic down
>   per protocol or per subnet, like most tools do, it groups bandwidth by
>   process.

You can find this tool in the package `nethogs`, so install it with

```
sudo apt-get install nethogs
```

---

The tool is started with the following command:

```
sudo nethogs <if>
# e.g. sudo nethogs eth0
```

The output looks [like this:](https://archive09.linux.com/var/uploads/Image/articles/154156-1.png)

You can cycle through various display modes with <kbd>M</kbd>; this will toggle between different measurement units and bandwidth usage vs. data amount.

The update interval can be set with the `-d` option, as described in the manpage nethogs(8).

Comment: Can you get it to also display which port the process is running on?

Comment: Hm, I don't think it does that. But you could easily grep `netstat -antp` for the PID, if you really need to know.

Comment: link is dead   xscfz